How to highlight the several sentences with \cite?
How to highlight citations in a revised manuscript
I've already tried the method above. But I have a little more question. Is it possible to change the background color instead of changing the color in the newenvironment?
'\newenvironment{hlbreakable}%
{\color{red}}%
{}'
I have tried to
'\newenvironment{hlbreakable}%
{\colorbox{yellow}{}}%
{}'
But it doesn't work. If someone know how to highlighting with several sentences with cite function, please let me know.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an short compilable TeX code you have tested so far!

Welcome. // On ctan.org you can find several packages for this purpose. See e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/easyreview . // Also using package soul may be a simple highlighter https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul .
